# xcode: How can I find the maximum attachement size for the email service provider the sender uses?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm working on an app in xcode which allows users to choose documents to be sent by mail, using MFMailComposeViewController. The problem is that the app crashes when the total size of the documents exceeds the allowed one.
Any idea how to fix that? How can I find the maximum attachement size for the email service provider the sender uses?

Answer (score 0):

The MFMailComposeViewController gets the information back from the server via the delegate

```
 – mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:
```

that is the method you need to implement and respond to the error message you get back.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate